# MERGE syntax SQL Server 2012 error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a question about the `MERGE` syntax for which I cannot find the answer.

I have the following case:

Step1:

```
create temp table #TempTbl
```

Step2: `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO T1 target 
USING T2 AS source ON (bunch of columns)

WHEN MATCHED 
    UPDATE 
        SET some columns from target equal some columns from source

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (bunch of columns) 
         VALUES (bunch of columns from SOURCE) 

OUTPUT $action, deleted.* into #TempTbl
```

What I need to know is for my above steps wouldn't I find only empty data in my temporary table `#TempTbl`, as I only stated `WHEN NOT MATCHED ... THEN INSERT`, not `DELETE`?

Second question, what type of column should `$action` be, as I'm having the error message:

> Column name or supplied values do not match table definition

Although I've tried to define the first column from my table both `varchar(100)`, `nvarchar(100)`, but with no luck. But, If I omit the `$action` field, then my statement works.

Comment: `@action` must be the same datatype as your first column in `#TempTbl`. To store something from `deleted` you must delete something - like `When NOT MATCHED by source THEN DELETE`

Comment: @BogdanM Do you want to store changed and/or inserted values?

Comment: Ok and what type should that be? As I wrote I tried that already, but with no luck

Comment: @gofr1 You don't need to use delete to store changes as `update` also writes to the deleted table...

Comment: @jpw: I want to store (in the temp table) the not Matched, Inserted rows. But I had the above statement as it is and it's not clear for me if it's incorrect or I just don't have all the information related to MERGE sytax

Comment: @jpw Thanks for noticing. My bad! Forgot about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the column that will hold the $action should be `nvarchar(10)`.

The following statement would add rows to the temp table for both `insert` and `update` (as the update is really a delete followed by an insert) but with different actions:

```
-- sample test data
create table t1 (col1 int, col2 int)
create table t2 (col1 int, col2 int)
insert t1 values (1,1),(2,1)
insert t2 values (2,2),(3,3)
create table #temptbl (dml_action nvarchar(10), col1 int, col2 int)

-- merge statement
merge into t1 target 
using t2 as source 
  on target.col1 = source.col1
when matched 
    then update set target.col2 = source.col2
when not matched by target 
    then insert (col1, col2) values (source.col2, source.col2) 
output $action, inserted.col1, inserted.col2 into #temptbl ;

-- sample result

select * from #temptbl

dml_action col1        col2
---------- ----------- -----------
INSERT     3           3
UPDATE     2           2
```

If you don't want the `update` rows you could wrap the entire batch into another statement like so:

```
insert #temptbl (dml_action, col1, col2)
select dml_action, col1, col2 
from 
(
    merge into t1 target 
    using t2 as source 
     on target.col1 = source.col1
    when matched 
       then update set target.col2 = source.col2
    when not matched by target 
       then insert (col1, col2) values (source.col2, source.col2) 
    output $action as dml_action, inserted.col1, inserted.col2 
) a
where a.dml_action = 'INSERT'
```